# Slick slider - check fields before change slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, slider, slick.js

I'm implementing a [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), in each slide there are different check boxes and text boxes.

When I press the button next, I need to check what's inside the text-boxes placed in each slide of my slick slider, if something goes wrong, the buttons must be disabled.I'm here trying to find out the right method to use. Nothing in the documentation and demo, just other questions like this but without the good example and solution for my case ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986838/check-condition-before-changing-slide-in-slick-slider)).

So, is there a method that just handle the button events without triggering the next slide? If is not implemented, how can I implement it?

I'm using this:

```
$('.container').on('beforeChange', function (slick, currentSlide) {
//check the fields, if the regex fails, disable the buttons.
}
```

but the buttons are disabled only in the next slide, because in the meanwhile the slide changes to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution, by changing the library:
change this row around line 2160 inside the Slick.prototype.slideHandler function:

```
_.$slider.trigger(beforeChangeEvent, [_, _.currentSlide, animSlide]);
```

with this:

```
var beforeChangeEvent = $.Event("beforeChange");  
_.$slider.trigger(beforeChangeEvent, [_, _.currentSlide, animSlide]);  
if(beforeChangeEvent.isDefaultPrevented()){  
    _.animating = false;  
    return;  
}
```

and then in your code declare a global variable and use it to check each field of your current slide, if a field is wrong the variable is false. In my case I just look at the error shown next to the field when the user focus out:

```
allow = true;  
 for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i ++){
    if ($(field[i]).next('span').css("visibility") === "visible") {      
            allow = false;     
    }  
  }
```

at this point I check what's the state of the variable allow. If the user wrote something wrong, the allow variable will be false, so I have to disable button next and prev:

```
   if(!allow){ //if the allow variable is false, one or more fields are wrong
      e.preventDefault();  //disable the buttons
    } else { //if allow is true (if there are no errors in the fields) 
      $form.slick('slickSetOption', 'swipe', allow, true); //enable the buttons 
    }
```