# jQuery Slick Slider - input request and form validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, slick.js

I have a small question. Is it possible to use slick for multi step form. I have 5 stages for input and radio, checkboxing. I can't understand the logic of transferring to the next slide. How to re-quest and validate the fields and if they are not filled in or marked do not move on to the next slide. Can anyone help because I can't find a clean and correct example. :)

```
 <!-- Slide 1 -->
 <div>
        <h1>Age 18</h1>
        <label class="element-animation1 btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
          <input type="radio" name="age18" value="1">Agree 18 age </label>
</div>
<!-- Slide 2 -->
 <div>
        <h1>User name</h1>         
          <input type="input" name="firstname" value="" required/>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $slider = $('.fade');
  var $progressBar = $('.progress');
  var $progressBarLabel = $('.slider__label');

  $slider.on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    var calc = nextSlide / (slick.slideCount - 1) * 100;

    $progressBar.
    css('background-size', calc + '% 100%').
    attr('aria-valuenow', calc);

    $progressBarLabel.text(calc + '% completed');
  });
  
  
    $slider.slick({
        swipe: false,
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 700,
        autoplay: false,
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: false,
        mobileFirst: true,
        focusOnSelect: false,
        accessibility: false,
        draggable: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See this answer from 2015:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32094339/4256497

.. and this discussion: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1138#issuecomment-230512604

I have not tried the first solution, but the solution suggested on GitHub is to create your multi-step form so that each Step/section has its own Prev and Next buttons, then you enable/disable them when doing JS form validation.

> I´m not sure if you already solved this, but what I did for a multi-step form with slick slider (just wanted to see what I can do with it) I just created to new buttons which are disabled by default, if the user now fills out an input-field, a validator validates the input and if all inputs are validated, the user may click "next" and it goes to the next slide. On the last slide I check if all the previous inputs are valid (because the the content is in fact the html, just hidden) and then send it via ajax.